# Why is EIT needed to story memory using rydberg atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, quantum-computer, rydberg-states

I was going through a paper explaining how the write-in and read-out efficiencies can be increased using cold atoms where they used Rydberg atoms, and mentioned that they were probed using EIT(Electromagnetically Induced Tranparency).

I have a brief idea about EIT, that it can be used to make a system transparent, which would otherwise be opaque.

I also know that the three states are used here, those are

1. The ground state
2. An excited state
3. A rydberg state

Can anyone explain how EIT is used here?

The DOI of the paper is: 10.1109/PHOSST.2017.8012667

Comment: What does EIT stand for here?

Comment: Electromagnetically Induced Transparency

Comment: well, if there is no EIT l, your input light can be scattered off the intermediate excited state and you lose information stored in the light.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for answering. Can I ask some other questions too?                                So the information is stored in the light. If it need not interact with the atom, why is it being passed through it?(sorry I'm not quite clear with this, yet)

Comment: @AmIAStudent , forgot to tag you

Answer (score 0):

EIT is not needed. It's just something that helps to make whatever the process better.

Also, it makes me feel that your question does not make sense by itself. EIT (three-level system coupled by two lights where one of them is extremely weak) is used for two scenarios: to store single-photon level photonic information, or to enhance interaction strength. The former one is developed as quantum memory so that the final state is metastable ($\lambda$-scheme), and the latter one is for the nonlinear quantum optics (photonic gate, ladder-scheme), which recently developed to use the Rydberg levels to further increase the interaction strength. These different applications seem to confuse you.